# Overwrite existing prototype method and retain the same 'this' scope

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype, function-prototypes

I've looked at multiple references but I cannot find a solution!

I dont' have access to the original prototype code

**EDIT:**

Let's assume the following already exists in my code base:

```
(function(){
    function Test() {
        this.game = 'rods';
    }
    Test.prototype.fail = function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log('A', this.game);
        }, 300);
    }
    var test = new Test();
    test.fail();
})();
```

I do NOT have access to the original declaration, this is outside my codebase, what I'm trying to achieve is a way to overwrite the default functionality of the fail method, but still retain the instance of the `THIS` keyword.

I've tried many different things, my goal is something similar to this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    Test.prototype.fail = function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log('B', this.game);
        }, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

I'd expect to see the exact same output, except the output should now be prefixed with a **B** instead of an **A**

I hope this is clear.

Comment: don't `.bind` and all should be working

Comment: It doesn't work @JaromandaX

Comment: not when you call it like `Utilities.prototype.add()` ... you need to instantiate an object something like `var x = new Utiltiies()` then `x.add()` will execute your code

Comment: I can't create a new instance, it needs to be called in the original code where it is originally called from @JaromandaX

Comment: changing the prototype wont stop the interval - but you should see `B rods` on the console if you `test.fail()` after one second - and the reason the initial fail function outputs `A undefined` is because the `this` in the interval callback isn't what you think it is (it's window in your codes case, undefined if you were in strict mode)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: in response to your update

This can't be right.

```
Test.prototype.fail = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        // since it's inside another function, 'this' no longer
        // refers to the instance of Test, but the global 'window'
        console.log('A', this.game);
    }, 300);
}
```

It would have to be something like this to work as I think it was intended:

```
Test.prototype.fail = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log('A', this.game);
    }.bind(this), 300);
}
```

You're saying an object has already been instantiated and `fail()` has already been called on it?  If you want to access the original function inside `setInterval`, **you can't** -- its scope is inaccessible from outside the function.  You also can't `clearInterval` without the return value of the original `setInterval` call.

If you want to override the function on an individual instance, you can, *if* you have access to the instance, but if `fail()` were already called, you couldn't clear the original interval.

```
test.fail = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log('B', this.game);
    }.bind(this), 1000);
};
```

But if your situation is really like your last edit says, then you have access to neither the `test` instance nor the interval nor the function in `setInterval`, then you cannot do what you suggest.

Comment: I cannot change the original prototype definition, you've changed the structure!

Comment: @ShannonHochkins That's not really clear from your question.  So you're saying you can't modify the first `Test.prototype.fail` (which can't be right as written), but you want to affect it by overriding the prototype?  Please update your question to be more clear.

Comment: The first edit explained all this, sorry it wasn't clear, how's this edit?